# Android SQLite Suggestion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've to implement a parent/child table in my application. Like this:

```
    Parent Table :  
      id  project_name
    ----------------    
      1     xyze
      2     abcd

    Child Table :
     id   p_id   part  quantity 
    ----------------------------
      1     1     A_1     2
      2     1     Y_6     1
      3     1     Z_2     2
      4     1     L_9     6
      5     2     E_1     1
      6     2     D_9     2
      7     2     A_1     8
      8     2     Y_1     2
```

Parent Table `id` is Foreign for child `p_id`. My concern is that child table will contain nearly 35000 rows. Will android SQLlite be able to handle 35000 approx rows? Will it take large storage space? Detailed answer will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: *My concern is that child table will contain nearly 35000 rows* and? there should be no problem ... unleast you would gone crazy and want to show all those rows in UI at the same time ... *Will it take large storage space?* obviously something about `35000* avg(row_size)`  - for(1     1     A_1     2) row_size would be less then 20 bytes - so whole table would take 700kB ...

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, SQLite can hold upto 2^64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19) rows in a single table.
See the following link for more details:
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Go to pt. 13 "Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table" in the above link.